# Different git versions on two projects on Android Studio

Tags: android, git

My project has a shared code base in the same repo.

```
.git
ProjectA
ProjectB
SharedCodeBase
```

I open `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` in the same Android Studio version (Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Canary 4 Build #AI-212.5284.40.2112.7863073, built on October 28, 2021) and each version uses its version of `git`.

In gradle, I set `println("## ${"git --version".execute().text.trim()}")` and:

- ProjectA prints `## git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)`
- ProjectB prints `## git version 2.14.1`

Both projects have the same Git configuration

[image]

I can see that I have two versions of git installed:

```
> git --version
git version 2.14.1
> which git 
/opt/local/bin/git
> /usr/bin/git version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
> /opt/local/bin/git version 
git version 2.14.1
```

So, although both projects git is set to `/opt/local/bin/git` one is using `/usr/bin/git version`.

Any idea why?

This is on a M1 MacBook

Comment: This is shell-dependent, but: running a command, `foo bar baz`, breaks up the words and then tries to run the first one (`foo` here). If that's an executable file, the shell *finds* the file by looking in your path. Your path is a shell variable, `$path` or `$PATH` typically, that lists which locations try in which order. Most shells import their path from the environment variable `PATH` at shell startup.

Comment: Each shell then runs various shell configuration scripts, such as `.profile` or `.zshrc` or whatever based on which shell it is and how they decided which files should be used in which startup cases (initial login shell vs others). These configuration scripts can *set* or *modify* the path. So the path you get, at the time the shell gets around to running some command, is from the environment `$PATH` setting as modified by whatever scripts the shell ran.

Comment: Various GUIs—I don't know anything about any of the ones you might be using—have their own configurations that can alter `$PATH` in the environment of any shell they start. So it seems likely that whatever you are using to build and run these projects, they're setting up different initial `$PATH` settings, or your shell startup scripts are looking at something—these are arbitrary programs so they can look at *anything they like* of course—and using that to choose what to put in their path setting.

Comment: The end result is that one project runs `git` out of `/opt/local/bin/git` and one runs it out of `/usr/bin/git`. But *where* that's coming from, well, there are a lot of places to fiddle with a path setting.